# Using Loop to create mutiple EventHandlers

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, eventhandler

I have a problem, that is I want to use loop to create multiple `EventHandlers`, 
 but my code shows nothing. What can I do?

```
    DynamicModule[{i, pos10 = {{}, {}}, pos11 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
                   pos12 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, pos20, 
                  pos21 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, pos22 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}}, 
 Graphics3D[{

   For[i = 1, i <= 2, i++,
    Print[i]; 
    EventHandler[
     Dynamic[{Translate[Cuboid[], pos11][[i]]},  ImageSize -> Tiny]
     ,
     {"MouseDown" :> {(pos10[[i]] = Mean@MousePosition["Graphics3DBoxIntercepts"])}, 
      "MouseDragged" :> (pos11[[i]] = pos12[[i]] + Mean@MousePosition["Graphics3DBoxIntercepts"] - 
          pos10[[i]]), 
      "MouseUp" :> (pos12 = pos11)}];
    ]},
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}]]
```

Comment: 1. Welcome to mathematica.SE :) 2. Use `Table`. 3. But even `Table[ stuff; {..}]` will give you nothing (`Null`) so skip `;`. More in [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18396#18396)

Comment: 4. You also need [IntroductionToDynamic](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html) especially *"A good trick to know"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed your code basing on the knowledge from the links from comments. With addition that: `Translate[Cuboid[], {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}]` is not really a list of `Cuboids` so you need to move `[[i]]` inside.

```
DynamicModule[{
  pos10 = {{}, {}},
  pos11 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
  pos12 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
  pos20,
  pos21 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
  pos22 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
  posInt
  },
 posInt[] := MousePosition["Graphics3DBoxIntercepts"];


 Graphics3D[{
   Table[With[{i = i},
     EventHandler[
      Dynamic[{Translate[Cuboid[], pos11[[i]]]}],
      {"MouseDown" :> {pos10[[i]] = Mean@posInt[]},
       "MouseDragged" :> (pos11[[i]] = pos12[[i]] + Mean@posInt[] - pos10[[i]]),
       "MouseUp" :> (pos12 = pos11)}]],
    {i, 2}]},
  PlotRange -> 3]

 ]
```

Good luck.